# Find the eigenvalues of 3-coupled equations matrix

Tags: plotting, matrix, eigenvalues

I'm trying to solve and and get the Eigenvalues (Natural frequencies later) of the matrix 3x3 for 3 Galerkin equation like in the pictures,,, where I solved them with one mode easily but with these coupled 3 equations, I'm still stuck.. so please help in order to plot the right plots..

```
d = 2*10^-6;  h = 2*10^-6;  b = 2*10^-6; l = 200*10^-6; EE = 1.66*10^11;  ε = 8.854*10^-12;  ρ = 2332; 
Subscript[α, 2] = (6*ε*l^4)/(EE*h^3*
d^3);        Subscript[α, 1] = 0;
Subscript[V, pull] = Sqrt[1.72/Subscript[α, 2]];

Subscript[ω, 1] = 3.51602; Subscript[ω, 2] = 22.0345; \Subscript[ω, 3] = 61.67; Subscript[σ, 1] = 0.7341; \Subscript[σ, 2] = 1.0185; Subscript[σ, 3] = 1.0008;

Subscript[ϕ, 1][x_] = Cosh[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 1]] x] - Cos[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 1]] x] -Subscript[σ, 
1]*(Sinh[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 1]] x] - 
  Sin[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 1]] x]);

 Subscript[ϕ, 2][x_] = Cosh[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 2]] x] - Cos[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 2]] x] -Subscript[σ, 
2]*(Sinh[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 2]] x] - 
  Sin[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 2]] x]);

 Subscript[ϕ, 3][x_] = Cosh[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 3]] x] - Cos[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 3]] x] -Subscript[σ, 
3]*(Sinh[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 3]] x] - 
  Sin[Sqrt[Subscript[ω, 3]] x]);


Subscript[λ, 19] = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(\(\([\)\(\*FractionBox[\(2 \*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(2\)] \*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DC\)], \(2\)]\), SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(s\)]\)[x, t])\), \(3\)]] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(1\)]\)[x] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(1\)]\)[  x]\)\(]\)\) \[DifferentialD]x\)\);



Subscript[λ, 110] = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(\(\([\)\(\*FractionBox[\(2 \*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(2\)] \*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DC\)], \(2\)]\), SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(s\)]\)[x, t])\), \(3\)]] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(1\)]\)[x] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(2\)]\)[x]\)\(]\)\) \[DifferentialD]x\)\);  



Subscript[λ, 111] = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(\(\([\)\(\*FractionBox[\(2 \*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(2\)] \*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DC\)], \(2\)]\), SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(s\)]\)[x, t])\), \(3\)]] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(1\)]\)[x] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(3\)]\)[x]\)\(]\)\) \[DifferentialD]x\)\)

Subscript[λ, 29] = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(\(\([\)\(\*FractionBox[\(2 \*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(2\)] \*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DC\)], \(2\)]\), SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(s\)]\)[x, t])\), \(3\)]] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(2\)]\)[x] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(2\)]\)[x]\)\(]\)\) \[DifferentialD]x\)\)


Subscript[λ, 210] = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(\(\([\)\(\*FractionBox[\(2 \*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(2\)] \*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DC\)], \(2\)]\), SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(s\)]\)[x, t])\), \(3\)]] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(2\)]\)[x] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(2\)]\)[x]\)\(]\)\) \[DifferentialD]x\)\)

Subscript[λ, 211] = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(\(\([\)\(\*FractionBox[\(2 \*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(2\)] \*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DC\)], \(2\)]\), SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(s\)]\)[x, t])\), \(3\)]] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(1\)]\)[x] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(3\)]\)[x]\)\(]\)\) \[DifferentialD]x\)\)

Subscript[λ, 39] = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(\(\([\)\(\*FractionBox[\(2 \*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(2\)] \*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DC\)], \(2\)]\), SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(s\)]\)[x, t])\), \(3\)]] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(3\)]\)[x] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(3\)]\)[x]\)\(]\)\) \[DifferentialD]x\)\)

Subscript[λ, 310] = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(\(\([\)\(\*FractionBox[\(2 \*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(2\)] \*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DC\)], \(2\)]\), SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(s\)]\)[x, t])\), \(3\)]] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(2\)]\)[x] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(2\)]\)[x]\)\(]\)\) \[DifferentialD]x\)\)

Subscript[λ, 311] = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(\(\([\)\(\*FractionBox[\(2 \*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(2\)] \*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DC\)], \(2\)]\), SuperscriptBox[\((1 - \(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(s\)]\)[x, t])\), \(3\)]] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(3\)]\)[x] \(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(3\)]\)[x]\)\(]\)\) \[DifferentialD]x\)\)

Subscript[C, 11] = Subscript[λ, 19] -Subscript[ω, 1]^2;       Subscript[C, 12] = Subscript[λ, 110];           Subscript[C, 13] = Subscript[λ, 111];

Subscript[C, 12] = Subscript[λ, 19] -Subscript[ω, 1]^2;       Subscript[C, 12] = Subscript[λ, 110];           Subscript[C, 13] = Subscript[λ, 111];

Subscript[C, 21] = Subscript[λ, 29];               \Subscript[C, 22] = Subscript[λ, 210] - Subscript[ω, 2]^2;        Subscript[C, 23] = Subscript[λ, 211];

Subscript[C, 31] = Subscript[λ, 39];               \Subscript[C, 32] = Subscript[λ, 310];                  \Subscript[C, 33] =  Subscript[λ, 311] - Subscript[ω, 3]^2;
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use `Subscript`. For example: code $\lambda_1$ as `λ[1]`.

Comment: What is $w_s$ and why have you defined $V_{pull}$ but not $V_{DC}$? I've rewritten your code but I need to know what those are to proceed with an answer.

Comment: sorry I defined already  bcz I used it in the following  next Q.. and   is the static deflection of the beam to find the Eigenvalues in Jacobioan Matrix

Comment: Yes but I can't compute your integrals without $w_s$ because $w_s$ is a function of $x,t$.

Answer (score 1):

I tried my best to clean up the code but parts are missing for you to provide, like $w_s, V_{DC}$:

```
d = 2*10^-6; 
h = 2*10^-6; 
b = 2*10^-6;
l = 200*10^-6;
ee = 1.66*10^11; 
ε = 8.854*10^-12; 
ρ = 2332; 
α[1] = 0;
α[2] = (6*ε*l^4)/(ee*h^3*d^3);
vpull = Sqrt[1.72/α[2]];
ω[1] = 3.51602;
ω[2] = 22.0345;
ω[3] = 61.67; 
σ[1] = 0.7341;
σ[2] = 1.0185;
σ[3] = 1.0008;

ϕ[k_, x_] := 
 Cosh[Sqrt[ω[k]] x] - Cos[Sqrt[ω[k]] x] - σ[k]*(Sinh[Sqrt[ω[k]] x] - Sin[Sqrt[ω[k]] x])

intg[p1_, p2_] := 
 Integrate[(2 α[2] vdc^2)/(1 - ws[x, t])^3 ϕ[p1, x] ϕ[p2, x], {x, 0, 1}]

matrix = MapIndexed[intg @@ #2 &, ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}], {2}] - 
   DiagonalMatrix[{ω[1]^2, ω[2]^2, ω[3]^2}];

eigval = Eigenvalues[matrix];
```